# cannot figure out how to chnage the location of PHP.exe in netbeans

Tags: php

I think I might be using a wrong instantiation of php on my computer (MySql metheds not working).  I cannot figure out how to set the location of php.exe. in netbeans

Comment: Do you really think this is enough information for anybody to be able to help you?

Comment: Tools->Options->PHP(icon)->General(tab)